# Тормозит ScrollView с CardView

Tags: android, cardview, scrollview

Тут такая проблема . Есть ScrollView внутри которого 4 CardView а внутри них по 1 изображению и по 1 тексту . При прокрутке тормозит Scroll что делать ? Заранее спасибо !
вот main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_row="8"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.geograf.ilhom4ik.geograf.Main"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="97dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="97dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/globe" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Страны мира"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="97dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="97dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/professo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Великие открыватели"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="97dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="97dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/dictionary" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Словарик"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="97dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="97dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/kas" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Проверь себя"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>``
```

Comment: Проблема может быть в изображениях - они могут быть слишком большими по размеру. Сделайте изображения размером по 20KB - 50KB

Comment: Спасибо большое все сработало ! Можете подсказать оптимальное разрешение изображения .

Comment: @ILHOM4IK, оптимальным будет, то, которое лучше всего будет выглядеть и не замедлять интерфейс.